# Evaluate DFT-downsampler-upsampler-IDFT block diagram

Tags: dft

[image: Question]

I am trying to solve the above question. I am not sure how to proceed. I know the formula for 64 point DFT of $x[n]$.

$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{63} x[n] e^{-j2\pi nk/64}$

But how can I find $R[k]$ and $Y[k]$? Can anyone please tell the relation?

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you at the absolute zero step?

Comment: more specifically, it will be very helpful to investigate the behaviour of compressor and expander stages... And note that DFT exhibits time-frqeuency duality.

Comment: I only know that the downsampler will take every second value of the $X[k]$ and $Y[k]$ will have an additional zero in every second sample of $R[k]$

Comment: ok. What about their effect on the other domain? (freq vs time) ? can you show that? Note that as I stated, DFT exhibits duality, you can takle advantage of this.

Comment: I learnt DFT of downsampler from: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/ReviewFourier/Downsampling_Aliasing.html.  So, by using duality, $r[n]=16(x[-n]+x[16-n])$ and $y[n]=r[2n]$? Please confirm.

Comment: so what would be the final answer?

Comment: let me show you how to find the DFT $R[k]$ of $r[n]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a finite length input sequence $x[n]$ of $N=64$ points, its 64-point DFT be $X[k]$. Then according to the block diagram you've provided, the signal $r[n]$ will be of $N/2$ points long and its $N/2$ - point DFT $R[k]$ will be related to $X[k]$ as :

$R[k] = X[2k]$, which will be manipulated as:

$$
\begin{align}
X[k] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} kn} ~~~,~~~ k=0,1,...,N-1 \\
R[k] & = X[2k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} 2kn} ~~~,~~~ k=0,1,...,N/2-1\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} + \sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} + \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} x[n+\frac{N}{2}] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \left( x[n]+x[n+\frac{N}{2}] \right) e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} \\ 
&= \text{N/2-point DFT} \{ r[n] \}\\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} r[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N/2} kn} \\
\end{align}
$$

hence we see that $r[n]$ is the sequence whose length (or period) is reduced to $N/2$ and is generated by adding the second half of $x[n]$ onto the first half.

Comment: thank you so much. Since $y[n]$ comes from 64 point IDFT, so the $y[n] = 16(x[-2n]+x[16-2n])$ ? Also I was not getting the correct relation for $r[n]$, since it comes from 32 point IDFT and not 64 point IDFT?

Comment: First note that, as shown above, 32-point r[n] is given by $r[n] = x[n] + x[n+N/2] = x[n] + x[n+32]$ for $n=0,1,...,31$. Now what's the relation beetween r[n] and y[n] ? you can show by duality that y[n] is a subperiodic signal formed by repetition of r[n] (with a scale factor)...